Discriminator loss and Generator loss is constant in cGAN
I have a financial .csv dataset. After preprocessing, I converted it into a graph structure with nodes, edges, and labels. My plan is to apply Graph Attention Network (GAT) on the graph data. I observed significant imbalance in the graph data. So I planned to use conditional GAN to generate synthetic samples. But after while training I observed that Discriminator loss is 1.0 and Generator loss as 0.6 from the first epoch and is not changing further. What could be the reason? This is my code:
class Generator(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, latent_dim, input_dim, label_dim):
super(Generator, self).__init__()
self.label_dim = label_dim  
self.model = tf.keras.Sequential(\[
layers.Dense(2048, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')  
\])

    def call(self, x, label):
        input_dim = tf.shape(x)[0]
        label_tiled = tf.tile(label, multiples=[1, self.label_dim])  
        combined_input = tf.concat([x, label_tiled], axis=1)
        output = self.model(combined_input)
        return output
class Discriminator(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, input_dim, label_dim):
super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
self.model = tf.keras.Sequential(\[
layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dropout(0.3),
layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dropout(0.3),
layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
\])

    def call(self, x, label):
        combined_input = tf.concat([x, label], axis=-1)
        return self.model(combined_input)

latent_dim = 100
input_dim = 37
label_dim = 2

generator = Generator(latent_dim, input_dim, label_dim)
discriminator = Discriminator(input_dim, label_dim)

